# Export multiples tables using package SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a question, about how to export more than one table to .csv using SSIS. I need to export about seven tables from Sql to .csv, for this I currently use the data import / export wizard. But I need something more automated, for example, use SSIS, so I created a package in SSIS but I could only export a table, because in the selection of tables or views I can only choose a table. So my question is how to export my seven tables dynamically to .csv using SSIS.

This is my package:

[image: package]

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSIS Dataflow works on the principal that it's an in-memory ETL engine. To keep things in memory, it forms a design-time contract between the source and destination that specifies this many columns, these data types.

You can dynamically swap out the source and destination connection attributes (read from server2 database B, write to \server\share\fileb.csv) but changing the shape of the data (6 columns instead of 7, all ints instead of strings, etc) can't happen at run time.

For 7 tables, I'd design 7 data flows with 7 OLE DB Sources to 7 Flat File Destinations. For as simple of a pattern I see, it's going to be the fastest approach to getting the development task done. Shouldn't take more than an hour.

If I had an unknown set of tables I need to dump to disk, then I'd look at an approach of using [Biml](https://bimlscript.com/) to describe the pattern. Heck, [Generate CSF file format from Database](http://bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/87) might be the exact pattern you're looking for. Install [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/BimlExpress), fix the connection string on line 23 & 75, adjust lines 28 and 29 to fit your use case and it might just work "as-is."

Comment: I did not know that tool, Bim Express. I have configured the code to my needs and it has worked pretty well for me. Thanks a lot @billinkc

Comment: Unfortunately BIML Express didn't install properly in my VS 2019 installation and I'm unable to fix. It does say "one or more extensions were loaded with deprecated APIs" but it still doesn't give me the BIML context menus.

Comment: @PeterX Yeah, that should be just a warning but VS will offer to disable the extension and if you accidentally click Yes, you'll have to go into ...some setting to re-enable it. If it's still busted, try their dedicated support section https://support.varigence.com